# Rudin 4.22 Let $f$ be a continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ (metric spaces). If $E$ is connected, then $f(E)$ is connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity, connectedness

> **Rudin 4.22.** Let $f$ be a continuous function from $X$ to $Y$ (metric spaces). If $E$ is connected, then $f(E)$ is connected.

Could someone check this proof:

**Proof:** I will show the contrapositive. Assume $f(E)$ is disconnected. So there exist sets $A$ and $B$ in $Y$ such that $ A \cap B = \emptyset $, $A$ and $B$ are open, $A$ and $B$ are nonempty and $f(E) \subset A \cup B$. I will show that $E$ must therefore be disconnected. First, 
$$f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B) = \emptyset $$
since if $ x \in f^{-1}(A)$ and $ x \in f^{-1}(B)$ then $x \in B $ and $x \in A$ which is impossible. Secondly, $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are open by continuity. They are obviously nonempty. Lastly, 
$$E \subset f^{-1}(A) \cup f^{-1}(B)$$
since if $ x \in E$ was not a member of either $f^{-1}(A)$ or $f^{-1}(B)$ then $f(x) \notin  A$ and $f(x) \notin B$ which means $f(x) \notin E$ which is contradiction. So $E$ is disconnected and contrapositive is shown.

Is this correct? it seemed a lot easier than the proof in the book, which makes me think its wrong.

Comment: Note that $E$ might be a proper subspace of $X$ and $f(E)$ a proper subspace of $Y$ so you need a few extra technicalities to deal with the subspace topologies (e.g., in general, what you can assume about $A$ and $B$ is only that $A \cap B \cap E= \emptyset$). Does that account for the extra complexities of the proof in the book?

Comment: But @RobArthan we are here dealing with metric spaces. So I guess one does not have to care about subspace topologies

Comment: @Rememberme: maybe, but the proof presented makes no appeal to special properties of metric spaces, so it is lacking some necessary details.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I see what you mean, A and B need not actually be disjoint in the space Y. Couldn't I just fix the separation of f(E) to be some G= $ A \cap f(E)$ and H= $B \cap f(E)$. Then replacing A and B with G and H, I have forced my separation of f(E) to be disjoint in Y and the rest follows?

Comment: @user243037: that only works if $E$ is open.

Comment: G and H would be open in the subspace topology. Since $f(E) \cap A $ is open in the subspace topology since A is open and f(E) is a subset of Y. Thats the definition of open sets in the subspace topology so G and H are open and so are there premise.

Comment: Keep following this through in your proposed proof: you now need to say something about $f^{-1}(G)$ and $f^{-1}(H)$, neither of which are necessarily open in $X$. I think you will find if you reread Rudin's proof that it is not much longer than yours and very neatly covers the problems that we've encountered with your proof (which is quite correct in the case when $E = Y$).

Comment: $f^{-1}(H) and f^{-1}(G)$ are necessarily open by continuity. G and H are open in Y (by the subspace topology) and therefor their inverses are open in X

Comment: I guess Im misunderstanding the subspace topology.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is restrict the continuous $f: X\to Y$ to a surjective map $g: X\to Z$ where $f(X)=Z$ . After this you can continue the same proof

Comment: You'd do better to restrict $f$ to $f^{-1}(E)$., then the proof as presented really does work, given some facts about subspace topologies.

Comment: Yeah we could restrict f to  $f^{−1}(E)$ but we only really need to restrict the separation of f(E) in Y to the two sets G and H such that $ f(E)=G \cup H$. G and H must be open, nonempty and disjoint of course, but this follows when me make use of the subspace topology.

Comment: No, You need to account for the fact that $f^{-1}(G)$ may not be in open in $X$. It will be open in $f^{-1}(E)$, by virtue of various properties of the subspace topology. When you say "open" in this kind of proof, you need to be careful about which space you are referring to.